# Change of coordinates from xy to x'y'

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the coordinate grids that define two separate coordinate systems:
[image]

Here the transformation $T(-x_0,-y_0)$ translates the x'y' coordinate system onto the xy coordinate system origin (0,0), and $R(- \theta)$ rotates x'y' coordinate system so that it aligns with the xy coordinate axes.

My book says the composite transformation:

$$ M_{xy,x'y'}=R(-\theta).T(-x_0,-y_0) $$ is the composite transformation matrix for transforming object descriptions from xy system to x'y' system.

My question is: isn't this the transformation that brings the coordinates of the x'y' system to our xy system? I mean were first translating the x'y' origin to our origin and then rotating so that x'y' aligns with our axes, and how is this changing our xy coordinates to x'y' coordinates?

Comment: From your description, it seems so that the transformation you have written does bring the X'Y' system to our original XY system.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh , I don't know if it's the book's mistake, but, it's written  there exactly like that, and it's written twice there,  so I don't know if it's a mistake there as well.

Comment: In general, the transformation which maps _coordinates_ of from one system to another is the inverse of the transformation that maps the coordinate _axes_ onto each other. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898029/question-regarding-basis-vectors-of-root-reference-frame) and related ones.